# Deduping Unique Pairs, on Data stored Consecutively, using RecordLinkage

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am using `recordlinkeage` to look for duplicates.  I am using several different searches to identify pairs.  I would like to merge my sets of pairs, to remove duplicates between the two methods.  I would like to have all the unique pairs, that are in either `getPairs(y)` or `getPairs(z)`.  As a final product I want a data.frame with all the unique combinations.

```
library(RecordLinkage) 

# Making some synthetic data
x <- rbind( mtcars , mtcars[2,])
x$name <- rownames( x )
x$nrid <- sample( 1:1000000 , nrow( x))

y = compare.dedup(
    x,
    blockfld=c("gear", "carb", "am", "name") ,
    phonetic = "name" ,
    phonfun = soundex) 

z = compare.dedup(
    x,
    blockfld=c( "am", "name") ,
    phonetic = "name" ,
    phonfun = soundex) 

# I know that I can see the details of my pairs
summary(y)
y <- getPairs(y)
z <- getPairs(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be simply a matter of using `dplyr::full_join`:

```
library(RecordLinkage) 
x <- rbind(mtcars , mtcars[2, ])
x$name <- rownames(x)
x$nrid <- sample(1:1000000, nrow(x))
y = compare.dedup(
  x, blockfld = c("gear", "carb", "am", "name") ,
  phonetic = "name", phonfun = soundex
) 
z = compare.dedup(
  x, blockfld = c("am", "name"),
  phonetic = "name", phonfun = soundex
) 

## Check the list components of y, z: safe to merge
all(names(y$pairs) == names(z$pairs))
all(y$frequencies == z$frequencies)

## Remove duplicates while combining pairs from both: key line
z$data <- dplyr::full_join(y$data, z$data)
getPairs(z)
```

If there are multiple things to merge, you can use `Reduce` to a list.
Let me know if this is not what you were going for.